# Sentence with two not-so-related parts

Tags: grammar, writing-style, syntactic-analysis

Quite a lot of articles in Wikipedia, especially about people, have sentences like this one:

> Author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse", he became the first non-European to win the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913.

(This is taken from the article [Rabindranath Tagore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabindranath_Tagore).)

This sentence makes two statements:

1. That Tagore was the author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse".
2. That he became the first non-European to win the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913.

It sounds kinda stylish, but the two things are not so related, so I don't really like this type of sentence. Is this considered correct grammar? Does this phenomenon have a name?

Comment: I'd go for *non-sequitur* or possibly *disjunct* -- I await more knowledgeable advice -- but your example isn't a good one. There is surely a relationship between writing profoundly sensitive, beautiful verse and winning the Nobel Prize for Literature.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't think it's disjunct -- there's a specific term for this construction that I can't remember.  The noun phrases `Author of...` and `he` are parallel.

Comment: @dbaseman They are parallel and definitely related in this case. How about an example like "Inventor of the automatic railway crossing and a number of signalling technology innovations, Jones won the Nobel Prize for Literature in 1945" where the second half is *completely* unrelated to the first half?

Comment: I don't see why you believe that they are "not so related". He won the Nobel Prize **for** _Gitanjali_. The sentence will seem less elliptical if it begins with something like "As the author of Gitanjali ...".

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think KTR has got it, *apposition*.  I also like coleopterist's comment above -- the phrases really are related, that's the point of the construction.

Comment: @Amir: Are you asking about the sentence structure itself? Are you making a distinction between examples where the two halves of the sentence are obviously related (as in your quote) or unrelated (like in my comment)? The question suggests the latter, but it's undermined by your quote.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I mostly ask about the name for this type of sentence. The structure of my example and of the "Inventor of the automatic railway crossing" example is the same and I want to know its name.

Answer (score 2):

The [‘Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582237262) (LSGSWE) describes such a construction as a **preface**, one of two types of **dislocation**, in which ‘a definite noun phrase is placed at one end of the clause, and a co-referential pronoun is used in the core of the clause.’

The example you provide is grammatical, and probably not unusual in academic prose. It is also found in a simpler form in conversation, as in this example from the LSGSWE: ‘This little shop, it’s lovely.’

Comment: And I think this one of those examples where dangling participles could easily happen.

Comment: I think this construction is probably more characteristic of journalistic than academic prose. You see it particularly when a reporter feels a need to remind readers who the subject is, and why the subject is 'newsworthy'.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, that too.

Comment: This sounds kinda right, but I can't browse that book on Amazon, and I can't find the definition of "preface" elsewhere (I tried several books about English grammar on Questia). If there's nothing else online, I guess that I'll try to find it in a library.

Comment: I believe I may have also heard this construct referred to as topicalization, where the preface noun phrase establishes the topic for the subsequent co-referential pronoun. But that wouldn’t explain “Me, I’m ready” or “Him, he’s not getting any.”

Comment: @tchrist. _Topicalization_ seems to be what the LSGSWE refers to as _fronting_, but it is not quite the same thing as _dislocation_. Rather, it means ‘placing in initial position a clause element which is normally placed after the verb.’ An example might be ‘This I do not understand.’ Utterances such as _Me, I’m ready_ or _Him, he’s not getting any_ look like special cases of dislocation, where the definite noun phrase at the beginning also happens to be a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)? That Tagore was the author of Gitanjali and its 'profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse' is used to modify the pronoun 'he'?

Answer (score 0):

I believe KTR's answer is correct: the name of the construction is "apposition".  I wanted to add some more notes on how it works (and I sort of like it actually...)

> Author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse", he became the first non-European to win the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913.

Now here, the first noun phrase *Author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse"* is sort of dangling, but it acts as an [antecedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_%28grammar%29) to *he* in the sentence's main clause.  The antecedent, so constructed, acts to qualify the main phrase through explanation or amplification.

Read this kind of apposition as sitting between two extremes.  On the one hand, you could have combined the two phrases using a conjunction **and**, which does not state or imply any causal connection:

- He was the author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse", and he became the first non-European to win the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913.

On the other hand, you could explicitly state a causal relationship, implying that he won the Nobel *because of* his authorship of *Gitanjali*.

- As the author of Gitanjali and its "profoundly sensitive, fresh and beautiful verse",  he became the first non-European to win the Nobel Prize in Literature in 1913.

The appositive construction sits between these two poles; the antecedent clause *"he was the author of..."* is offered up as only a hint, or as supporting context for the main clause *"he won a Nobel Prize..."*.